# Why this formula is written with this Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, matrix, formula

In section 4 of [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6072216&tag=1) paper, the following formula is presented to zero-center the kernel matrix `K` of size `p`:
[image: formula]

And this is the code I have corresponding to the above formula:

```
K = K - (1/p)*(K*ones(p,1))*ones(1,p) - (1/p)*ones(p,1)*(ones(1,p)*K) + (1/p^2)*sum(sum(K));
```

I'm confused about the relation of the code to the actual formula in the paper. In particular about the last two members `- (1/p)*ones(p,1)*(ones(1,p)*K)` and `(1/p^2)*sum(sum(K))`.

Can someone please explain it?

Comment: What are you confused about? It looks like the `e` in your equation is just a vector of `1`s ? The rest is just applying it while avoiding to do some of the operations explicitly (in the last term).

Comment: I'm confused because the last term should be the matrix formed by the sum of `K`'s elements divided by `p^2`  while the term before should be the matrix formed by `-1/p`. This seems different from `- (1/p)*ones(p,1)*(ones(1,p)*K) + (1/p^2)*sum(sum(K));` which is K's multiplied by `-1/p` and the scalar value of the sum of `K's` elements divided by `p^2`.

Comment: Please let me know if my comment is not clear

Answer (score 5):

Well, the code is not completely correct. The third term includes a `K` which is not there in the presented formula from the paper. Additionally, the last term does not multiply with ***e e**<sup>T</sup>*. However, the latter can be omitted in this case since MATLAB will automatically add the scalar to all the elements in the matrix. The same applies for the third term, so it can be omitted there as well.
Here is a correct version of the line with the above mentioned simplification:

```
K = K - (1/p)*(K*ones(p,1))*ones(1,p) - 1/p + (1/p^2)*sum(sum(K))
```

---

We can simplify further by making only one call to `ones`, since `ones(p,1)*ones(1,p)` gives you the same result as `ones(p)`. Furthermore `sum(sum(K))` can be replaced with `sum(K(:))`.
It would look like this:

```
K = K - (1/p)*K*ones(p) - 1/p + (1/p^2)*sum(K(:))
```

---

Now we can compare this to what would be the *one-to-one implementation* of the formula. Therefore, we will use `e = ones(p,1)` to represent **e**. To get ***e**<sup>T</sup>*, you can just transpose `e` with `.'`. So the formula can be written as follows:

```
K = K - (1/p)*K*e*e.' - (1/p)*e*e.' + ((e.'*K*e)/p^2)*e*e.'
```

Note that `e.'*K*e` just calculates the sum of all elements in `K`, which is equal to `sum(K(:))`. This is valid because `e = ones(p,1)`.

Let's generate some sample data and compare the results:

```
rng(8);             % make it reproducible
p = 3;              % size of matrix
K = randi(10,p);    % generate random matrix
e = ones(p,1);      % generate e-vector

K1 = K - (1/p)*(K*ones(p,1))*ones(1,p) - 1/p + (1/p^2)*sum(sum(K))
K2 = K - (1/p)*K*ones(p) - 1/p + (1/p^2)*sum(K(:))
K3 = K - (1/p)*K*e*e.' - (1/p)*e*e.' + ((e.'*K*e)/p^2)*e*e.'
K4 = K - (1/p)*K*e*e.' - (1/p)*e*e.' + sum(K(:))/p^2
```

Here is the result:

```
K1 =
    8.0000    5.0000    4.0000
    9.6667    2.6667    4.6667
    9.3333    1.3333    6.3333
K2 =
    8.0000    5.0000    4.0000
    9.6667    2.6667    4.6667
    9.3333    1.3333    6.3333
K3 =
    8.0000    5.0000    4.0000
    9.6667    2.6667    4.6667
    9.3333    1.3333    6.3333
K4 =
    8.0000    5.0000    4.0000
    9.6667    2.6667    4.6667
    9.3333    1.3333    6.3333
```

Comment: Just one word: speachless. You really overkilled it, thanks SO MUCH! I would give you two +1 if it was possible :)

Comment: Could you please give a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309619/why-this-matlab-and-c-codes-produces-different-results) question?

Comment: @justHelloWorld I think you got your answer there already in the meantime... The difference in `KC` is not really significant and can be improved by using double.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but as I've written in the updated answer it doesn't seem to be the problem :(

Comment: @justHelloWorld Could you tell me why the answer has been *unaccepted* even though it provided the solution to your question?