# Why this matlab and C++ codes produces different results?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

+I'm trying to implement a matlab algorithm in C++.

This is the matlab code:

```
p = 3;
K = [3 4 5; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
e = ones(p,1);
K2 = K - (1/p)*K*ones(p) - 1/p + (1/p^2)*sum(K(:))
[V_K,D_K] = eig(K2);
```

While this is the analogous C++ code using OpenCV:

```
float data[] = {3, 4, 5,
                4, 5, 6,
                7, 8, 9};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_32F, data);
float p = K.rows;
cv::Mat CK = K - (1/p)*K*cv::Mat::ones(p,p,CV_32F) - 1/p + (1/std::pow(p,2))*cv::sum(K)[0];
cv::Mat eigenvalues(1,p,CK.type()), eigenvectors(p,p,CK.type());
cv::eigen(CK,eigenvalues,eigenvectors);
```

The matlab code print:

```
CK =

4.3333    5.3333    6.3333
4.3333    5.3333    6.3333
4.3333    5.3333    6.3333

0.5774    0.6100   -0.1960
0.5774   -0.7604   -0.6799
0.5774    0.2230    0.7066

16.0000         0         0
      0   -0.0000         0
      0         0    0.0000
```

While the C++ code produces:

```
CK=[4.3333335, 5.3333335, 6.3333335;
 4.3333335, 5.3333335, 6.3333335;
 4.333333, 5.333333, 6.333333]

eigenvectors=[0.53452265, 0.56521076, 0.62834883;
 -0.41672006, 0.8230716, -0.38587254;
 0.73527533, 0.05558794, -0.67548501]

eigenvalues=[17.417906;
 -0.33612049;
 -1.0817847]
```

As you can see, the values are *completely* differents (even the ones of `CK`!). Why this happens and how can I avoid it?

**Note** that I'm not completely sure that my C++ implementation is correct!

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622012/matlab-and-c-differ-with-cos-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151609/precision-differences-in-matlab-and-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) question related, but they seem related to *slightly* differences, while here the error is *huge*!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to follow to suggestions in comments & answers. Unfortunately, none of the solution proposed solved the problem. First of all I tried to use the `Eigen` library with `float` precision. This is the code using the `Eigen::Map` structure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783329/opencv-cvmat-and-eigenmatrix/14874440#14874440):

```
//in order to map OpenCV matrices to Eigen, they need to be continous
assert(CK.isContinuous());
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> CKEigenMapped (CK.ptr<float>(), CK.rows, CK.cols);
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> CKEigen = CKEigenMapped;
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> es (CKEigen,true);
std::cout<<"Eigenvalues:"<<std::endl<< es.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
std::cout<<"Eigenvectors:"<<std::endl<< es.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
```

Then I tried to convert from `float` to `double` through `CK.convertTo(CK, CV_64F)`:

```
//Double precision
CK.convertTo(CK, CV_64F);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> CKEigenMappedD (CK.ptr<double>(), CK.rows, CK.cols);
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> CKEigenD = CKEigenMappedD;
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> esD (CKEigenD,true);
std::cout<<"Eigenvalues:"<<std::endl<< esD.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
std::cout<<"Eigenvectors:"<<std::endl<< esD.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
```

Finally I tried to use the `cv2eigen` function (I thought that `Eigen::Map` could have been wrong) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115488/how-to-initialize-a-eigen-matrix-from-an-opencv-cvmat-or-from-an-array-which):

```
//Double precision, cv2eigen
Eigen::MatrixXd X=Eigen::MatrixXd(CK.rows,CK.cols);
cv2eigen(CK,X);
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> esDD (X,true);
std::cout<<"Eigenvalues:"<<std::endl<< esDD.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
std::cout<<"Eigenvectors:"<<std::endl<< esDD.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
```

And these are the results corresponding to the 3 previous solutions:

```
Eigenvalues:
(-4.17233e-07,0)
          (16,0)
(-3.37175e-07,0)
Eigenvectors:
(-0.885296,0)   (0.57735,0)  (-0.88566,0)
 (0.328824,0)   (0.57735,0)  (0.277518,0)
 (0.328824,0)   (0.57735,0)  (0.372278,0)
Eigenvalues:
          (16,0)
  (8.9407e-08,0)
(-1.88417e-16,0)
Eigenvectors:
  (0.57735,0)  (0.480589,0)  (0.408248,0)
  (0.57735,0)  (0.480589,0) (-0.816497,0)
  (0.57735,0) (-0.733531,0)  (0.408248,0)
Eigenvalues:
          (16,0)
  (8.9407e-08,0)
(-1.88417e-16,0)
Eigenvectors:
  (0.57735,0)  (0.480589,0)  (0.408248,0)
  (0.57735,0)  (0.480589,0) (-0.816497,0)
  (0.57735,0) (-0.733531,0)  (0.408248,0)
```

As you can notice:

1. None of them correspond to the Matlab results ( :'( )
2. There is a difference between using `double` and `float`
3. There is no difference between using `Eigen::Map` and `cv2eigen`

**Please note** that I'm not expert in `Eigen` and I could have used `Eigen::EigenSolver` in a wrong way.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is starting to be a mess! This is the code using Amradillo. **Notice** that `A` has the same values of `K2` (`CK` in C++):

```
arma::mat A(3,3);
A   << 4.333333333333333 << 5.333333333333333 << 6.333333333333333 <<arma::endr
    << 4.333333333333333 << 5.333333333333333 << 6.333333333333333 <<arma::endr
    << 4.333333333333333 << 5.333333333333333 << 6.333333333333333 <<arma::endr;
arma::cx_vec eigval;
arma::cx_mat eigvec;
eig_gen(eigval,eigvec,A);
std::cout<<"eigval="<<std::endl<<eigval<<std::endl<<"eigvec="<<std::endl<<eigvec<<std::endl;
```

And these are the printed values:

```
eigval=
    (+1.600e+01,+0.000e+00)
    (-4.010e-17,+3.435e-16)
    (-4.010e-17,-3.435e-16)

eigvec=
    (+5.774e-01,+0.000e+00)    (-5.836e-02,+3.338e-01)    (-5.836e-02,-3.338e-01)
    (+5.774e-01,+0.000e+00)    (+7.174e-01,+0.000e+00)    (+7.174e-01,-0.000e+00)
    (+5.774e-01,+0.000e+00)    (-5.642e-01,-2.284e-01)    (-5.642e-01,+2.284e-01)
```

Seriously, what's wrong with all these libraries? They don't even closely agree with each other!

Comment: Have you tried switching to `double`?  Looks like it could be a precision or rounding error.

Comment: I am not sure your C++ implementation is correct either, there may be estimation errors in there.

Comment: Which library is correct? (Look at the eigenvalues first).

Comment: @Bathsheba the matlab code is the original one, so it's the correct one

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ouch, I was afraid that could be the problem...but this could be a problem since the OpenCV matrices that I'm using are in `float` :( I'll try to convert them to `double`, but I don't know if that's possible

Comment: Doubles in matlab are 64 bit Floats in C++. They both use the IEEE 754 format of encoding.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if you run `eig(single(K2))` in MATLAB it will give practically the same result as it does now. Its not that.

Comment: Break it down to smaller checks. One line or subexpression at a time. Then it should be easy to see where the two diverge and what is wrong.

Comment: @justHelloWorld - the Armadillo answer is correct.  `+1.600e+01` is `16`. Small eigenvalues such as `(-4.010e-17,+3.435e-16)` are essentially zero. Any eigenvectors corresponding to zero eigenvalues are typically garbage. The garbage is dependent on the nature of each eigendecomposition algorithm.

Comment: @justHelloWorld - further note: to check the validity of each answer, reconstruct the decomposed matrix and compare it to the original matrix. For example, `[v,l] = eig(K2); K3 = v*l*inv(v); error = norm(K2-K3)`. See a linear algebra textbook for more information.

Comment: @hbrerkere thanks for your comment, I didn't know that eigenvectors relatives to small eigenvectors are garbage, thanks for the tip. Anyway, if that's case, also the results from `Eigen` are correct. The only weird thing is that for using the `float` precision (first of the three codes in **UPDATE**) the order of the eigenvalues (and relative eigenvectors) is different, while this doesn't happens with `double` precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cv::eigen` [assumes](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#eigen) that the input matrix is **symetric**, and yours is not. that is why the difference is there.

I believe openCV does not have support for eigenvectors of non-symmetric matrices, you may need to use another library.

**Update:** PCA (principal component analysis) *is* an eigenvector decomposition, so you may be able to go that way, but the best would be to use some specific math library, such as EIGEN or ARMADILLO.

Comment: See also the [eig_gen()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_gen) and [eig_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) functions in Armadillo. The eig_gen() function handles general (non-symmetric) matrices, while the eig_sym() is optimized for symmetric matrices.

Comment: @justHelloWorld Updated

Comment: @justHelloWorld Let me look a bit further, but the results are quite close, as your eigenvalues are good in all, and *some* eigenvectors are different.

Comment: @AnderBiguri hbrerkere suggested (in the question comments) to ignore the eigenvectors relatives to near-zero eigenvalues, since they are garbage. In that case the results are the same for both `Eigen` and `Armadillo` libraries (even if in the `float` case for some weird the order of the eigenvalues is different). Do you agree?

Comment: @justHelloWorld oh damn,  its too early in the morning. Indeed an eigenvector for a nearly zero eigenvalue is rubbish. The results you get in both Armadillo and Eigen are right.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm sorry dude, in HK the sun is going down already :D I hope to be in your same timezone when I get back home in italy ;)

Comment: @justHelloWorld haha ;) Happy to help. Consider accepting the answer if it worked